# How can I open the dialog when clicking the value that has been plot on chart in vue-chartjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to open a `v-dialog` when I click a point on a chart. I bound the dialog's `v-model` to `this.dialog` (a data property), but setting `this.dialog` to `true` doesn't open the dialog. When I check the value of the `this.dialog`, it is really `true`. Why doesn't the dialog open?

```
<line-chart
    :chart-data="datacollection"
    :options="optionscollection"
    />

this.optionscollection = {
  onClick: function(evt, item) {
    this.dialog = true;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onClick` handler does not have its context bound properly, so `this` is *not* the Vue component instance there. Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead:

```js
this.optionscollection = {
  onClick: (evt, item) => {
    this.dialog = true;
  }
};
```

[image: Edit Opening v-dialog on chart click]